# There is no error with this javascript code yet it does not work. Is there a secret error I can't see?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, object, error-handling

I have this JavaScript code I've been using for weeks now and no error has ever occurred with it but now all of a sudden it just doesn't work! Here is the code itself:

```js
function DB(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.content = [];
  this.add = function(value) {
    this.content.push(value);
  }
  this.get = function(id) {
    return this.content[id];
  } 
}

var name = new DB("Names DB");

name.add("Test Name");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're executing this code in the global scope, `name` already exists as `window.name`. Therefore, `name = new DB("Names DB")` coerces the second half into a string and you essentially run `name = '[object Object]'`.

Wrap everything in a function to use a non-global scope:

```
(function() {
    // Your code
})();
```

Or choose a different variable name.

Comment: Wow I didn't know there was such a variable! Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

That code is in conflict with attribute `window.name` you need to enclose your code in a function or drastically remove the attribute `name` from `window` object.

```js
delete window.name; // Remove attribute.

function DB(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.content = [];

  this.add = function(value) {
    this.content.push(value);
  }

  this.get = function(id) {
    return this.content[id];
  }
}

var name = new DB("Names DB");
name.add('Test Name');
```